# As a solo miner how can I prioritize my own unconfirmed transactions?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, confirmations, zero-confirmation, coin-age-priority

Is it possible to prioritize my own unconfirmed transaction through my mining machines without being in a pool? And if its possible how can I do that?

Comment: How much hashrate do you have access to?

Comment: "without being in a pool", do you mean you are solo mining?

Comment: @PieterWuille Correction to my comment I sure mean solo mining. 
I have access to 160GH/s

Comment: Interesting question, but 160ghs on the Bitcoin network right now is a drop in the ocean. Might be good for a new alt coin, but not for long if it becomes popular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are the pool itself, or are solo mining you can use the `prioritisetransaction` command to add weight to your own transaction, if you are a client of a pool you do not have any control over **what** you are mining.

Comment: If I understand Prioritisetransaction is a client side thing that is configured on bitcoin core software mining node, and it's only possible if i'm a pool myself (solo miner) with how much hashrate would that be possible?

Answer (score 2):

With 150GH/s, at the time of writing, you would find one block every 1500 years.

That means if you were solo mining, you'd be able to control the contents of a block once every 1500 years.

Or in other words: not at all.

Comment: He could get lucky and front load the first two or three blocks. Lol